# GCC linking with kerberos for compiling with CURL statically

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to compile a program that uses `pthread` and `curl` statically. I get some errors when trying to link with `kerberos` library. Openssl version is `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`. This is the `gcc` command :

```
gcc -o test2 test2.cpp utils.cpp /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a -static -lpthread -lstdc++ -lcurl -lidn -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -fno-stack-protector;
```

This is the output : http://pastebin.com/D3Zp02Ea

OS :

```
cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

UNAME :

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-371.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 18:23:07 EDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I already tried reinstalling it from here `http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/` and then tried to link it, same errors.

What is the problem?

Comment: Notice that cURL includes potential support for lots of protocols/options you may not need to support, if all you need is to perform some "regular" HTTP/HTTPS requests (no exotic protocols, no complex authentication schemes) you can get away with way less dependencies; Kerberos in particular IIRC is needed almost only if you want to perform HTTP requests authenticated against a Windows server using NTLM authentication - stuff that I'm not even sure many browsers outside IE can do. If that's not an actual use case of yours you can consider leaving it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a lib in the MIT package called libkrb5support, which I had to include in my linker when doing a similar task.  I had to include 5 libraries in total, you have the other four.  The number of different libs in the MIT distribution is maddening.